# Как сделать выбор из базы данных по дате и времени?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite3

Есть код для баззы данных, в таблице сохраняется **task_deadline**, отвечающая за время, и я хочу сделать отсортировку даты, указанной в **task_deadline**, через **SELECT** чтобы дата в таблице была равна сегодняшней дате, дабы дальше с этим работать, но я не знаю как сделать отсортировку по дате, потому что в sqlite3 нет типа данных **Date**, а как правильно сделать через тип данных **TEXT** или **INT** я не знаю. Помогите пожалуйста.

Вот код для базы данных:

```
import sqlite3
import os
import logging
from dotenv import load_dotenv
from win10toast import ToastNotifier
import datetime

ENV_LOCATION = os.path.relpath(r'.env')

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

load_dotenv(ENV_LOCATION)


class DatabaseHandler:
    #TODO Remodeling this class to be more redundant
    __DB_LOCATION = os.getenv('DB_LOCATION')

    def __init__(self, db_location=None):
        """ Initialize db class variables """
        if db_location is not None:
            """ Allows to set db location through argument """
            self.connection = sqlite3.connect(db_location)
        else:
            self.connection = sqlite3.connect('1')
                
        self.cur = self.connection.cursor()


    

    def select(self, table_name):
        self.cur.execute(f"SELECT * FROM {table_name};")

    def insert(self, table_name, task_name, task_details, task_addition_date, task_deadline):
        self.cur.execute(f"INSERT INTO {table_name} VALUES (:task, :details, :add_date, :deadline);",
                         {'task': task_name, 'details': task_details, 'add_date': task_addition_date,
                          'deadline': task_deadline})
        self.cur.execute(f"SELECT * FROM {table_name} WHERE TaskDeadline='{task_deadline}';")
        
    def remind(self, table_name,  task_deadline):
        
        self.cur.execute(f"SELECT * FROM {table_name} WHERE {task_deadline} = strftime('%d-%m-%Y %H:%M', 'now', 'localtime', '-5 hours');")
        
        
        if result:
            print('DA')
        
        
    def delete(self, table_name, record):
        self.cur.execute(f"DELETE FROM {table_name} WHERE TaskName=(:item);",
                         {'item': record})


    

    def update(self, table_name, task_name, new_task_name, new_task_details, new_task_deadline):
        self.cur.execute(f"UPDATE {table_name} SET TaskName=(:new_name), TaskDetails=(:new_details), \
                            TaskDeadline=(:new_deadline) WHERE TaskName=(:old_name);",
                         {'new_name': new_task_name, 'new_details': new_task_details, 'new_deadline': new_task_deadline,
                          'old_name': task_name})

    def create_table(self, table_name):
        self.cur.execute(f""" CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS {table_name}(  TaskName TEXT, \
                                                                        TaskDetails TEXT, \
                                                                        AdditionDate TEXT, \
                                                                        TaskDeadline TEXT)""")

    def transfer_data_between_tables(self, table1_name, table2_name, key_value):
        self.cur.execute(f"INSERT INTO {table2_name} SELECT * FROM {table1_name} WHERE TaskName=(:value);",
                         {'value': key_value})
        self.delete(table1_name, key_value)

    def drop_table(self, table_name):
        self.cur.execute(f"DROP TABLE IF EXISTS {table_name}")
        print(f"Dropped the {table_name} table")

    def __enter__(self):
        return self

    def __exit__(self, ext_type, exc_value, traceback):
        self.cur.close()
        if isinstance(exc_value, Exception):
            self.connection.rollback()
        else:
            self.connection.commit()
        self.connection.close()
```

Comment: Как Вы добавляете время? То есть `cur.execute('INSERT INTO my_table VALUES ?', (datetime.datetime.now(),))` так или как-то по другому? В Вашем коде есть только участок, где передается аргумент - в функции `insert` и всё.

Comment: Время добавляется в формате TEXT, т.е **cur.execute(f"INSERT INTO {table_name} VALUES ?", {'deadline': task_deadline})** где task_deadline сохраняется в формате данных TEXT

Comment: Просто если Вы вызываете функцию `datetime.datetime.now()` или `datetime.datetime.utcnow()`, то формат будет `2021-08-29 14:06:32.237048`, и когда Вы сравниваете с `{task_deadline} = strftime('%d-%m-%Y %H:%M', 'now', 'localtime', '-5 hours');`, то строчки не будут совпадать из-за секунд и микро секунд, потому что он сравнивает их как строчки. Попробуйте `datetime.datetime.utcnow().replace(minute=0, second=0, microsecond=0)` и `strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:00', datetime('now', '-5 hours'))`.

Comment: Т.е вот так? **self.cur.execute(f"SELECT * FROM {table_name} WHERE {task_deadline} = strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:00', datetime('now', '-5 hours'))")**

Comment: И `task_deadline.replace(second=0, microsecond=0)` в `cur.execute(f"INSERT INTO {table_name} VALUES ?", {'deadline': task_deadline})`. Вам время нужно только часы или ещё и минуты?

Comment: Еще и минуты, дабы я потом сделал так, чтобы при наступлении времени task_deadline приходило уведомление

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/129068/discussion-between-ivapop-and-be3y4uu-k0t).

Answer (score 2):

Вам нужно удалить секунды и микросекунды, потому что из-за оных строчки не будут совпадать с `datetime('now', '-5 hours')`, т.к. всегда (почти) секунды и микросекунды не будут равны.

Из нашего обсуждения я написал примерный код:

```py
import datetime
import sqlite3

 
db = sqlite3.connect('database.db')
cursor = db.cursor()
 
cursor.execute('''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS records
                  (record text, lifespan text)
               ''')

date = datetime.datetime.utcnow().replace(second=0, microsecond=0) # Удаляем лишние
cursor.execute('''INSERT INTO records
                  VALUES (?, ?)
               ''', ('Something 1', date))

date = datetime.datetime.utcnow().replace(second=0, microsecond=0)
date -= datetime.timedelta(hours=5)
cursor.execute('''INSERT INTO records
                  VALUES (?, ?)
               ''', ('Something 2', date))
db.commit()

# тут из-за <= берутся и старые записи,
# но это для того, что если вдруг Вы сделаете запрос в последнюю
# секунду и минута будет равна уже M+1, то запись будет проигнорирована,
# но можно и просто =
cursor.execute('''SELECT * FROM records
               WHERE lifespan <= strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:00', datetime('now', '-5 hours'))
               ''') 
        
print(cursor.fetchall())
```